# QPushbutton does not connect

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, signals-slots

In the following code I'm trying to replace "original text" with "new text" when "click" button is pressed. I dont get any errors, but the label's text doesnt change.

```
 QPushButton *button=new QPushButton("click");

QLabel *label=new QLabel("original text");
QVBoxLayout *layout=new QVBoxLayout();
QString word("new text");
QWidget *window=new QWidget();

layout->addWidget(button);
layout->addWidget(label);
QPushButton :: connect(button,SIGNAL(clicked()),layout,SLOT(setText(word)));
window->setLayout(layout);
window->show();
```

Comment: The approach is wrong, I'd suggest that you reread the documentation. In brief, you cannot specify the instance like `word` during the connection.

Comment: I tried this instead  QPushButton :: connect(button,SIGNAL(clicked()),layout,SLOT(setText("new text")));

Comment: Of course, that's just wrong, read the documentation, please. You simply misunderstood the mechanics of signals & slots.

Comment: i guess i did. thanks much!

Comment: How you can say you dont get any error, if you dont even check the return value of connect for error? -1 for that not proofable claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major point here is that signatures of signal and slot should be **compatible**. In other words, you cannot connect signal `clicked()` to slot `setText(QString const&)` simply because `setText` has different signature, i.e. accepts a parameter of the `QString const&` type.

What you could do is create a *"forwarding"* class which would define your custom parameterless slot `setText` so that it could be connected to signal `clicked()`, for example:

```
class Forwarder: public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  Forwarder(QObject* parent = 0): QObject(parent),
                                  word("new text"),
                                  label(new QLabel("original text")) {
    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("click");
    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    QWidget*     window = new QWidget();

    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(setText()));

    layout->addWidget(button);
    layout->addWidget(label);
    window->setLayout(layout);
    window->show();
  }

protected Q_SLOTS:
  void
  setText() 
  { label->setText(word); }

private:
  QLabel* label
  QString word;
};
```

Note how your custom `setText` can be connected to `clicked`, and merely forwards the `setText` invocation to `label`.

Two more points that are wrong in your code:

- You **cannot** pass instances during the connection like:

  ```
  ...
  QString word("new text");
  ...
  connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), layout, SLOT(setText(word))); // Odd!
  ...
  ```
- You probably meant to connect to `label` rather than `layout`.
  Since you want to change the text on `label`, you need to call
  `setText` method for `label`, not `layout`. Furthermore, `layout`
  (as a pointer to an instance of `QLayout` class) doesn't even have `setText` method.

I encourage you to reread the documentation to sort of feel why the approach presented above is the valid one, while yours is not, and could never be.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH! I am reading the documentation again right now and slowly gaining clarity as to why my code didnt work. and yes, I did mean to use label. Thanks again.